# ESLint: Failed to load config "next/babel"

Tags: javascript, github, next.js, vercel, babel-jest

I'm facing this problem deploying my site on vercel from my [Github repo](https://github.com/hammadsohail/ecommerce_sanity_stripe).

Here is my complete vercel log file.

> [22:42:45.867] Cloning github.com/hammadsohail/ecommerce_sanity_stripe
> (Branch: main, Commit: e24ccfc) [22:42:46.012] Previous build cache
> not available [22:42:46.658] Cloning completed: 790.981ms
> [22:42:46.946] Running "vercel build" [22:42:47.589] Vercel CLI 28.9.0
> [22:42:47.997] Running "install" command: `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`... [22:43:00.681]  [22:43:00.681] added 331 packages, and audited 332 packages in 12s [22:43:00.681]
> [22:43:00.681] 82 packages are looking for funding [22:43:00.682]
> run `npm fund` for details [22:43:00.683]  [22:43:00.683] found 0
> vulnerabilities [22:43:00.708] Detected Next.js version: 13.0.6
> [22:43:00.713] Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7+...
> [22:43:00.714] Running "npm run build" [22:43:01.111]  [22:43:01.111]
> ecommerce@0.1.0 build [22:43:01.111] > next build [22:43:01.111]  [22:43:01.480] info  - Loaded env from /vercel/path0/.env
> [22:43:01.665] Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous
> telemetry regarding usage. [22:43:01.666] This information is used to
> shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features. [22:43:01.667] You can
> learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate
> in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
> [22:43:01.668] https://nextjs.org/telemetry [22:43:01.668]
> [22:43:01.956] info  - Linting and checking validity of types...
> [22:43:02.455] error - ESLint: Failed to load config "next/babel" to
> extend from. Referenced from: /vercel/path0/.eslintrc.json
> [22:43:02.463] info  - Creating an optimized production build...
> [22:43:02.518] info  - Disabled SWC as replacement for Babel because
> of custom Babel configuration ".babelrc"
> https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/swc-disabled [22:43:03.248] info  -
> Using external babel configuration from /vercel/path0/.babelrc
> [22:43:08.424] Failed to compile. [22:43:08.424]  [22:43:08.424]
> ./components/Navbar.jsx [22:43:08.425] Module not found: Can't resolve
> 'next/Link' in '/vercel/path0/components' [22:43:08.425]
> [22:43:08.425] Import trace for requested module: [22:43:08.425]
> ./components/Navbar.jsx [22:43:08.425] ./components/index.js
> [22:43:08.425]  [22:43:08.426] ./lib/client.js [22:43:08.426] Module
> not found: Can't resolve '@sanity/Client' in '/vercel/path0/lib'
> [22:43:08.426]  [22:43:08.426] Import trace for requested module:
> [22:43:08.426] ./lib/client.js [22:43:08.426]  [22:43:08.426]
> [22:43:08.426] > Build failed because of webpack errors [22:43:08.465]
> Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1

Also in my Vscode its giving me

> error:error - ESLint: Failed to load config "next/babel" to extend
> from. Referenced from: C:\Users\hammad
> sohail\Desktop\ecommerce\Ecommerce.eslintrc.json

My `packages.json`:

```
{
  "name": "ecommerce",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.9",
    "@sanity/client": "^3.2.0",
    "@sanity/image-url": "^1.0.1",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.25.0",
    "canvas-confetti": "^1.5.1",
    "next": "12.1.0",
    "next-sanity-image": "^3.2.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "stripe": "^8.209.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "eslint": "8.13.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.4",
     "next": "13.0.6"
  }
}
```

My `.eslintrc`:

```
  "extends":["next/babel","next/core-web-vitals"]
```

I am trying to deploy my site on vercel. Anyone has this similar issue?

Comment: Update**

This issue was fixed after deleted Node modules folder, then runing npm install -legacy-peer-dep